# IE Web driver - Login button test button doesn't work

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I was testing a login page using IE web driver. The login did not redirected to the next page though the username and password was inserted properly. Kindly provide me a solution.

This is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class IELogin {
    public static void main(String []args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver","C:\\Users\\dell\\Downloads\\IEDriverServer_Win32_3.9.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        driver.get(URL);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lemail']")).sendKeys("xxx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='lpassword']")).sendKeys("xxx");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-save mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn']")).click();

        System.out.println("Test Pass");

    }

}
```

This worked for both Chrome and Firefox. But didn't work for IE.

Comment: refer [Guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for putting perfect title to question.

Answer (score 1):

Because IE is slow

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@id='lemail']"))).sendKeys("xxx");
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='lpassword']"))).sendKeys("xxx");

 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn-save mat-raised-button mat-button-base mat-warn']"))).click();
```